# Does the iOS has a support for MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I'm trying to stream the data(media) from the iPhone to a windows compact embedded device which has a MTP initiator. I want to know whether there is an MTP responder support in iOS so that it can stream data into the windows embedded device?

Comment: What have you tried? What language you doing this in? i.e. `objective-c` and/or `swift`. Have you done any research at all? Please share all details of what you have tried are you will find no one will help. Users on here like to help those who help themselves so you need to show that you have made an attempt at trying to resolve this yourself and done some research beforehand and your question doesn't show any of that.